# Conditionally Include Aggregation Pipeline Stages

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a function which get me some orders based on given parameters.
But, the parameter can be empty, in that case I want to leave the `$match` alone.

This is the code which I currently have:

```
if(req.query.status && typeof(req.query.status) == 'array'){
        var match = {
            $in: req.query.status
        };
    }else if(req.query.status){
        var match = req.query.status;
    }else{
        //when empty find all statuses
        var match = null;
    }


 Order.aggregate(
    {
        $match: {
            'shop.nameSlug' : req.query.nameSlug,
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$status"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "status.status" : match
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            status: {
                $addToSet: "$status"
            },
            number: {
                $first: "$number"
            },
            date: {
                $first: "$date"
            },
            comment: {
                $first: "$comment"
            }
        }
    }
).exec(function(err, orders){
})
```

when `match` is null, there a no orders returned, because mongo is searching for fields equals to null. How can I remove that `$match` when `match == null`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you mean to do is build the whole pipeline depending on the options provided. It' is just a data structure after-all.

You are also incorrectly testing for an "array" and you should be using [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) because [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) would actually return `"object"` and not `"array"`.

Moreover you really want that condition in the **first** pipeline stage to optimally select the documents as well, in addition to being added after [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) where needed:

```
var pipeline = [
  { $match: 
      Object.assign(
        { 'shop.nameSlug' : req.query.nameSlug },
        (req.query.status) 
          ? { "status.status": (req.query.status instanceof Array)
            ? { "$in": req.query.status } : req.query.status }
          : {}
      )
  },
  { $unwind: "$status" },
  ...(
    (req.query.status)
      ? [{ "$match": { 
          "status.status": (req.query.status instanceof Array)
           ? { "$in": req.query.status } : req.query.status
       }}]
      : []
    ),
    { $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      status: { $addToSet: "$status" },
      number: { $first: "$number" },
      date: { $first: "$date" },
      comment: { $first: "$comment" }
    }}
];    


Order.aggregate(pipeline).exec(function(err, orders){

})
```

Given a `req` object with something present in `status` you get:

```
// Example stucture
var req = {
  query: { 
   nameSlug: "Bill", 
   status: "A"
  },
};

// Pipeline output as:

[
    {
        "$match" : {
            "shop.nameSlug" : "Bill",
            "status.status" : "A"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$status"
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "status.status" : "A"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id",
            "status" : {
                "$addToSet" : "$status"
            },
            "number" : {
                "$first" : "$number"
            },
            "date" : {
                "$first" : "$date"
            },
            "comment" : {
                "$first" : "$comment"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

With an array:

```
var req = {
  query: { 
   nameSlug: "Bill", 
   status: ["A","B"]
  },
};

// Pipeline output as:
[
    {
        "$match" : {
            "shop.nameSlug" : "Bill",
            "status.status" : {
                "$in" : [ 
                    "A", 
                    "B"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$status"
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "status.status" : {
                "$in" : [ 
                    "A", 
                    "B"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id",
            "status" : {
                "$addToSet" : "$status"
            },
            "number" : {
                "$first" : "$number"
            },
            "date" : {
                "$first" : "$date"
            },
            "comment" : {
                "$first" : "$comment"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And with nothing:

```
var req = {
  query: { 
   nameSlug: "Bill", 
   //status: ["A","B"]
  },
};

// Pipeline output as:
[
    {
        "$match" : {
            "shop.nameSlug" : "Bill"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$status"
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id",
            "status" : {
                "$addToSet" : "$status"
            },
            "number" : {
                "$first" : "$number"
            },
            "date" : {
                "$first" : "$date"
            },
            "comment" : {
                "$first" : "$comment"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

So you can see where the parts are conditionally included depending on the values provided.

---

### Using $filter

You really should be using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) here instead. It's a lot more efficient than [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and you really are not grouping anything. All you really want is filtered arrays. So that's all you conditionally add:

```
var pipeline = [
  { $match: 
      Object.assign(
        { 'shop.nameSlug' : req.query.nameSlug },
        (req.query.status) 
          ? { "status.status": (req.query.status instanceof Array)
            ? { "$in": req.query.status } : req.query.status }
          : {}
      )
  },
  ...(
    (req.query.status)
      ? [{ "$addFields": { 
          "status": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$status",
              "cond": {
                [(req.query.status instanceof Array) ? "$in" : "$eq"]:
                  [ "$$this.status", req.query.status ]
              }
            }    
          }
       }}]
      : []
    )
];
```

The choice there is between [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) and [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) for the comparison test, depending on what is supplied. You can optionally wrap the whole thing in [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) if you "really mean" to use a "set" in the result. But it's generally looking like you simply want to "filter" values out of the array.

With the same expectations of a single value:

```
var req = {
  query: { 
   nameSlug: "Bill", 
   //status: ["A","B"]
   status: "A"
  },
};

/* 1 */
[
    {
        "$match" : {
            "shop.nameSlug" : "Bill",
            "status.status" : "A"
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields" : {
            "status" : {
                "$filter" : {
                    "input" : "$status",
                    "cond" : {
                        "$eq" : [ 
                            "$$this.status", 
                            "A"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

An array:

```
var req = {
  query: { 
   nameSlug: "Bill", 
   status: ["A","B"]
  },
};

/* 1 */
[
    {
        "$match" : {
            "shop.nameSlug" : "Bill",
            "status.status" : {
                "$in" : [ 
                    "A", 
                    "B"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields" : {
            "status" : {
                "$filter" : {
                    "input" : "$status",
                    "cond" : {
                        "$in" : [ 
                            "$$this.status", 
                            [ 
                                "A", 
                                "B"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Or nothing:

```
var req = {
  query: { 
   nameSlug: "Bill", 
   //status: ["A","B"]
  },
};

/* 1 */
[
    {
        "$match" : {
            "shop.nameSlug" : "Bill"
        }
    }
]
```

Where if you don't need to filter, then you simply drop the additional pipeline stage.

Comment: w0w. What.An.Answer! Briljant! I'm not yet an expert with mongo / mongoose so the `$group` code was from another answer on SO :)

I get the error `MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'` how can i solve that?

Comment: @NVO You need MongoDB 3.4 for that pipeline stage. But you can pretty much simply use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) instead, it's just that you actually need to name all the fields you want explicitly, instead of just the one to "merge". Just like you do in `$group`.  But you should really use `$project` and `$filter` in any modern MongoDB version greater than v3. Which you should be running since anything less is no longer officially supported.

Comment: Ahh. I have it working now. The reason for the $unwind was that an order can have multiple statuses and I want to only check on the last one, not the first match, because all orders are paid before sending, which results in sent orders when I want to filter on 'paid'.

Comment: clever with the spread operator! i've never liked to initialize a specific variable for the aggregation pipelines