# Include system variables inside MongoDB aggregation based on a condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

So let us say I have a system variable called `runMatch`

and I have the following start of an aggregation:

```
    {
        $match: {
            'book.title': req.body.title,
        }
    } .......etc
```

Can I use the `runMatch` inside the aggregation and check if it is true, I will apply the match stage, if not I won't apply it. Imaginary, something similar to this:

```
        if(runMatch){
            $match: {
                'book.title': ObjectId("5d98d3374ae55e747c61acee"),
             }
        }
```

Or if there is a way to use the `runMatch` in any way?

Comment: See this: [Conditionally Include Aggregation Stages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362486/conditionally-include-aggregation-pipeline-stages).

Comment: So it's like when you build the query in code prior to making DB call, you can conditionally add a stage.